# How can I trigger a push notification from a button clicked inside my app?

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, firebase-cloud-messaging

Simple question I think.
I'm still fairly new to Swift and Firebase so bear with me.

#### My current set up

I successfully integrated Cloud Messaging and can send messages either through the testing function or with pre-created messages (scheduled or not).

#### My question

How can I trigger messages being sent, either pre-defined messages and if possible custom messages defined by the app and/or modified by e.g. user input? (For example: User presses button. Triggers message "xyz" to be sent to one specific other user, also predefined by the app.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I have not found a single thing that would help me understand this.

Comment: You can have each user be a "topic" that they are subscribed to (eg their UID is the topic name). Then, you can send a message to that topic. Explanation of subscribing to and sending to topics is covered here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging

Comment: There are tons of examples of how to do this task in the Firebase documentation. It could be anything from leveraging cloud messaging, to server functions or just the basic functionality of Firebase as it's an event driven database; e.g. if my app is observing a node in firebase and you write data to it (e.g. a message), then my app will respond to that. Do you have some code you've tried?

Comment: I’ll read into what @jnpdx sent and then update post on wether or not I got it worked out

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an HTTP Request to send FCM message within your app!

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send